# Makefile using directory structure for source and object files

Tags: makefile

Facing some issue and need advice related to makefile within a directory structure.
I have a folder structure which is as follows:

```
Project 
->Src
->Obj
```

The Project contains "Makefile", "Src" contains `.c` files and "Obj" will contain `.o` files

I'm able to compile and build the code when there is no folder structure, however facing some issue with compilation when using the nested folder structure.

Below is the code snippet for reference:

```
CC = gcc
SRCDIR: Src
OBJDIR: Obj

SRCS = one.c two.c 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
```

Here I want the `.o` to be fetched from its respective directory i.e. all `.c` files from `SRCDIR` and all `.o` from `OBJDIR`.

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
```

But it gives error an error.

Also I tried something like

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c,
```

but then it fetches `.c` in `OBJDIR\SRCDIR\.c` and gives error

Also one more thing; I want `TARGET` to be fetched from `$(OBJDIR)`, otherwise it always tries to compile all files while building.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at it:

```
SRCS = one.c two.c

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

so after this, `OBJS` will have the value `one.o two.o`.  Then we see:

```
$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
```

You don't show us what `MAIN` is but say it's `program`, then this line says:

```
program: one.o two.o
```

But that's not what you want to build and that's not what your makefile actually builds.  You want to build `Obj/one.o Obj/two.o`

*Edited based on your question edits*

> `.c.o:`

You cannot use suffix rules for this: suffix rules can ONLY build targets in the exact same directory as the source file.  If you want to build targets in a different directory than the source file you must either use explicit rules for each target, or use pattern rules.

> `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c`

I don't know of it's a typo or not, but you are missing a slash between `$(SRCDIR)` and `%.c`.  Aside from that, this is the correct formulation of the rule for what you said you wanted to do.

> But it gives error an error.

This is meaningless for us.  If you want help you must tell us (via cut and paste of the actual output, not paraphrasing) exactly what error messages you got.

> `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c,`

I'm assuming that the comma at the end of this is a typo in your question and was not present in the actual makefile.

But this pattern won't do what you want.  Say make wants to build a target like `Obj/foo.o`.  That matches the above pattern with a stem (the part that matches the `%`) of `foo`.  That means that to apply this pattern rule, make must find (or find a way to build) `%.c` with `%` set to `foo`, or the file `foo.c`, which doesn't exist (you have `Src/foo.c`, not `foo.c`).

> but then it fetches .c in `OBJDIR\SRCDIR\.c` and gives error

I can see no possible way that the makefile as you've described it will try to fetch `OBJDIR\SRCDIR\.c` (even assuming you meant `OBJDIR/SRCDIR/.c` with forward slashes) so there must be some confusion here.

> Also one more thing; I want TARGET to be fetched from $(OBJDIR), otherwise it always tries to compile all files while building.

I don't understand this at all.  What is `TARGET`?  There's nothing named `TARGET` in the makefile as you've shown it to us.